# Firefox is not working

Tags: firefox, xorg

I am using 12.04, but my Firefox is not working.

```
alex@alex: firefox
X_PCOMGlueload error for file /usr/lib/firefox/libxpcom.so
Xibxulso: connot open shared object file:
No such fire or directory.
```

Any help would be apperciate.

Comment: are you using 32bit or 64bit Ubuntu? And are your firefox downloaded form their site or installed from standard repo?

Comment: 32 bit ubuntu, at first my firefox is working ,recently i upgraded my gcc version, there after its not working.

Answer (score 5):

## Reset Firefox ! [image: ;)]

Open terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>).

Enter the command below to reset and clean all data in your Firefox:

```
mv .mozilla/firefox .mozilla/firefox.bak
```

Then restart Firefox.

If it doesn't work, try this command:

```
sudo apt-get clean; sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get remove firefox; sudo apt-get install firefox
```

Comment: I wouldn't do that, the profile has little to do with library dependencies.

Comment: Hey January....! Nice to see you around! yeah you are right...
Well, somebody else seek this question may find it helpfull :D

Answer (score 1):

Try that:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall firefox
```

Comment: I would add `sudo apt-get update` first. Just to make sure he has latest repository information.

Comment: Thanks for replys, apt-get is not working, it seems. if try with sudo apt-get update , error--->>apt-get:/opt/quartus/linux/libstdc++so.6:version 'GLIBCXX_3.4.15 not found required by apt-get.This is the problem, any solutions?

Comment: Uh-uh. That looks bad. Please start a new question with the *exact*  error messages of apt-get. Also, post /var/log/dpkg.log. Something is rotten in your system, and probably you will have to install the libs manually.

Comment: Thanks for reply, At first i upgraded my gcc version, after that i got blank screen.I tried with unity --reset, again i got my desktop , and very next day same problem repeated but  unity  not working.just i typed as sudo apt-get update

Comment: It showed error like apt-get:/opt/quartus/linux/libstdc++.so.6:version:GLIBCXX_3.4.11 and GLIBCXX_3.4.15 not found(Required by apt-get)

Comment: and another error apt-get:/opt/quartus/linux/libstdc++.so.6:version "GLIBCXX_3.4.11 and GLIBCXX_3.4.15 not found required by /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libapt-pkg.so.4.12

Comment: Yep, you have shot down your system. You installed a new version of the main system libraries, and programs that are compiled with the old version are broken. Please post a new question describing all that in detail, maybe someone knows how to help you.

Comment: and i have the content of /var/log/dpkg.log, but how post here,that content is more,kindly tel me alternate method.

Comment: defenetely i wil post  new question, but noone to give reply , ur the first person, really thanks

Comment: how to get help? really iam struggling, kindly help me anybody

Comment: To post your dpkg.log, use http://paste.ubuntu.com.

Comment: Sir, i posted the content of /var/log/dpkg.log, thanks

Comment: Sir, have u seen the content of /var/log/dpkg.log

Comment: Sir, any solution?

Comment: I told you what you should do (ask a new, specific question). And no, I have not seen the dpkg.log, because you have not provided a link.

Comment: Sory, this is the link,http://paste.ubuntu.com/1229780/ and  i already i posted a new question , but no replys.